# How to combine 3 input text arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a little problem because I don't know how to combine my dynamic added input text fields.

I explain you: In my HTML form I can add dynamically some text inputs to add a new ticket which contains 3 fields: SERIE, FOLIO, NUMERO:

Right away I show you an image to make you understand how my form looks: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmWUBgKqLm-KhlEDlgzMA9VLZBwo

And here is the HTML code:

```
    <div style="border:1px solid black; border-color: #19296C; padding:10px; border-radius:10px;"><h3>Boletos adquiridos</h3>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="ticketQty">Cantidad de boletos comprados: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="ticketQty" id="ticketQty" placeholder="Cantidad de boletos comprados" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="input_fields_wrap ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <label for="serie">Serie: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="serie[]" id="serie" placeholder="Serie" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90 || event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122'>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <label for="Folio">Folio: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="folio[]" id="folio" placeholder="Folio" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode <= 46'>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <label for="Numero">Numero: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="numero[]" id="numero" placeholder="Numero" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode <= 46'>
                </div>
                    <button class="add_field_button" data-mini="true">Agregar Boleto</button>
                </div>
                </div>
```

When I take the values of my 3 input text with PHP, I do the next:

```
    if(isset($_POST["serie"]) && is_array($_POST["serie"])){
    $subject = implode(", ", $_POST["serie"]);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["folio"]) && is_array($_POST["folio"])){
    $subject1 = implode(", ", $_POST["folio"]);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["numero"]) && is_array($_POST["numero"])){
    $subject2 = implode(", ", $_POST["numero"]);
    }
```

But when I print the array's values I can only get the values like this:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmWUBgKqLm-KhlJn1QOEkWBit6gq

And I would like to create a variable combining the values. For example

Serie--------Folio--------Numero

A-------------001-------------1

A-------------001-------------2

The question is, how can I combine the values given in my arrays to create a structure like I want and then insert the ticket in my database concatenating my results.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through one of the arrays and create an array that combines the corresponding elements of all of them.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($_POST['serie'] AS $i => $serie) {
    $result[] = array('serie' => $serie, 
                      'folio' => $_POST['folio'][$i],
                      'numero' => $_POST['numero'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried what you recommend but I only got the word "Array" on my screen :\

You know what could I be doing wrong??

Comment: You can't echo an array, use `var_dump($result)` to see the contents of the results.

Comment: Ooooh dude sorry, I am just an amateur programmer but I like so much to learn.

And yes, with that code my tickets combine correctly the values, but now I have another doubt, how can I create a new variable which contain theese combined array values ordered because I need to insert the combined array values in one only database field.

In my database I would need to see every ticket (conformed by the 3 text fields in my form) separated with a coma for example or a semicolon doesn's matter.
For example: A 500 001, A 500 002, A500 003

I hope you can help me Barmar, thank you so much.

Comment: You shouldn't put comma-separated values in a database field. Now you have another thing to learn: database normalization. Google it.

Comment: I just insert it in an acces database, the database is not very complex because only uses 3 or 2 tables it's not normalized:

Something like this:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmWUBgKqLm-KhlNdgYHubuwKJ1LZ